# Need to update an element in array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update the store = 465 , AisleName = 59 and set AisleSort = 34 by this update query for the below code

```
db.getCollection('products').update({'AvailableOnStores.AisleName': { '$eq': '59' }, 'AvailableOnStores.StoreNumber': { '$eq': '465' } }, { '$set': { 'AvailableOnStores.$.AisleSort': 34 } } )
```

Then it is updating with 34 in the 465 store but we don't have that AisleName in that store. we have that aisle name in store 423. I cannot check element by element, as I am checking all these from json file that contains sort and AisleName for each store.

```
{

"ProductCode" : "6786777",
"AvailableOnStores" : [ 
    {
        "StoreNumber" : "465",
        "Price" : "19",
        "AisleSort" : 9,
        "AisleName" : "Checkout Lane",
        "AisleLocations" : [ 

            {
                "bayNumber" : 6,
                "description" : "Checkout Lane",

            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "StoreNumber" : "423",
        "Price" : "1",
        "AisleSort" : 5,
        "AisleName" : "59",
        "AisleLocations" : [ 
            {

                "description" : " Aisle 59",
            }, 
            {

                "description" : "Aisle 25",

            }, 
            {

                "description" : "Aisle 4",

            }
        ]
    }
],
"NotAvailableOnStores" : [],
"IsPricingVaries" : false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the document in which both of these conditions gets true you should modify your query like this

```
db.getCollection('products').update(
  {
   'AvailableOnStores':{
         $elemMatch:{'AisleName':{ '$eq': '59' },'StoreNumber':{ '$eq': '465' }}}   
  }, 
  { 
   '$set': {'AvailableOnStores.$.AisleSort': 34 } 
  } 
)
```

For reference read this documentation on mongodb [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks @mZparacha . Now it's working. I think my db is updating little slow.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved so it could help others in future